# How come my website is first on Google but without PageRank?

Tags: seo, google-search, pagerank

Well, my question says everything. I don't understand very well how Google chooses which page to pop first in a search. for example I have a website, and I run it through a PageRank scanner website and it says it as 0/10. But in my country, when you search for the key words it shows up first.

I want to know the PageRank of every page inside the website because I am thinking in re-design it. Right now the information is divided in about 7 pages inside the website and I want to erase them and have only one large page with all the information on it.

The thing is that I don't know if that would affect my position on Google searches because I read that Google penalizes the website if it is pointing to a page and its broken, or if it only has one page and it doesn’t have inside links, etc.

Comment: PageRank is no longer publicly available so you actually no idea what your PageRank is, Furthermore, PR is only a small factor in Google's ranking algorithm. Good content is going to overcome most of the issues you mention as well well as URL redirects.

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it!

Comment: See also: [What is PageRank and how do I get it?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15/what-is-pagerank-and-how-do-i-get-it)

Comment: See also: [How to get Google PageRank (from the toolbar) to increase from 0?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/69127/how-to-get-google-pagerank-from-the-toolbar-to-increase-from-0) -- which pre-dates Google killing off public PageRank, so it isn't a good candidate for a duplicate question

Comment: See also: [How to find Google PageRank without third party tools?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84955/how-to-find-google-pagerank-without-third-party-tools) which has an answer about Google disabling public PageRank including links to statements from Google and a time line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the pagerank scanner is showing 0/10 is because Google no longer provides access to a sites PageRank value and so they have no value to display to you. As @John Conde points out in his comment PageRank is only a small factor in the overall ranking algorithm. Currently it is reported that there are over 200 "signals" used by Google in ranking a site. The fact that your site ranks number 1 for relevant searches is a good thing.

As for re-designing your site as long as you maintain high quality content on your site and use appropriate redirects in your server configuration to redirect from those high ranking pages to the new redesigned pages then you should maintain a reasonable rank, though I should point out that changes to a website, especially larger site wide redesigns or re-architecting your sites URL structure can have a temporary impact on your ranking while the new addresses are ranked and taken into consideration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Chris Rutherfurd .
I would like to know what do you mean by "use appropriate redirects". How can I appropriatly redirect all the pages to my new main index page?

Comment: What you do is add a `.htaccess` file to your site root with 301 redirects for each of the existing pages to your new main index page. What this will mean is that whenever a connection is made to the former page it will be redirected to the new index page.

Comment: Would the `.htaccess` have any impact in the rank of the website?

Comment: No, .htaccess simply helps you configure your server on a site by site basis.